# Receiving message from client using csocket::receive on c++

Tags: c++

client sends message to server and buffer size returned from csocket::receive function is correct size of the message. server receive correct buffer size of real message but the message itself is shorter than it should be:

onsend:

```
UpdateData();
if(m_ClientSocket.send(m_strMessage.GetBuffer(m_strMessage.GetLength()),m_strMessage.GetLength()){}   
else {AfxMessageBox(L"failed to send message")}
```

onreceive:

```
TCHAR strRec[256]=L"";

int n=CSocket::Receive(strRec,256);
```

---

if i send for ex: 12345

`n` will be 5
but message in strRec will be shorter, say 12.

Comment: I won't post as an answer as I don't have a reference to hand, but I remember from my MFC days it was fairly well known that CSocket simply didn't work.  If you want to stay in MFC use CASyncSocket instead - generally done by inheriting from it and overriding certain methods.

Comment: already tried works the same.

Comment: Not sure this fits your symptom, but - you've got the same definition for TCHAR on both sides - not somehow narrow on the send and wide on the receive...?

Comment: yeah, CString on send and TCHAR on receive

Comment: That in itself doesn't guarantee the same character width at each end as TCHAR is conditionally defined as either wide or narrow, generally depending on whether UNICODE is defined.  And by the way, your call to receive should be `CSocket::Receive( strRec, 256 * sizeof(TCHAR) );`